# iOS 10 - NSURLSession is very slow compared to iOS 9

Tags: objective-c, ios10, nsurlsessiondatatask

I've a service which gives JSON response of about 15000 records. When calling that service in iOS 9 (iPad Air) using `NSURLSession dataTask` its taking 2 to 3 minutes, but the same service is taking 10 to 12 minutes in iOS 10.

Has anyone come across the same situation?

I am using NSURLSession dataTask with delegates.

Comment: show your api calling code ..

Comment: If you want help, show your code!

Answer (score -1):

Why are you using a data task for something that takes minutes to fetch?  Use a download task.  Data tasks are meant for fairly short requests....

Comment: That is *absolutely* true.  You're talking to the person who originally wrote the documentation for that API.  If you're downloading a piece of content that's big enough that it takes minutes to download, you should almost invariably be writing it to disk and parsing it later, and doing so a piece at a time rather than keeping such a huge piece of data in RAM.  You're potentially running on a device with less than a GB of RAM.